# How to allow jobs to run after-hours when IIS app pool may be idle?

Tags: iis, hangfire

I'm trying to get my head around using hangfire with a .net core web app.  The examples seem simple enough, however I have questions.

If I want to run a job on a cron schedule, even if the iis app pool is asleep, shouldn't I consider putting the hangfire server in a windows service?

If using both the server and the client in the web app, the documentation mentions to modify the root .net config file to allow your app to be always running.
http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/deployment-to-production/making-aspnet-app-always-running.html

Why can't you simply set the app pool timeout to 0 instead?

The other option is to put the hangfire server as part of a windows service project.  I'd rather not mess with a windows service if its not really needed.  That need being that to run a scheduled job (via a cron schedule) to execute, even if no users are making requests to the app to prevent the app pool from going to sleep.  Setting the app pool idle timeout should do the same thing should it not?

Comment: What do you have against running it as a Windows service? If your code doesn't need an HTTP context to function, then it shouldn't be in a web application. If you *really* want to do what you've described, Hangfire's documentation describes how to put your app pool into always running mode. But I don't recommend it. It's an abuse of what web applications are meant for.

Comment: That's what you should challenge the Hangfire developers. That project if used in web apps leads to more issues than ever if you search around the internet, and Microsoft never recommends such. Run a Windows service please, which is mandate to make things right.

Comment: Microsoft actually did write a blog post recommending it in 2017 (but it's deleted now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **never** expect a website to run an extended job like that. They're designed to run quick (ish) calls and actions and return results. The suggestion is to use a Windows Service. As soon as you start messing with App Pool timeouts etc, you're asking for trouble.

I can revise this answer now with the release of Net Core 2.2. MS have added in a "Background Task" service which allows stuff to run on the server while the server is active:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: The job itself wont take long, but it I want to run on a schedule.